# IBM Watson Java SDK - 4.0.0 - com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.RetryRunner missing

Tags: java, maven, ibm-cloud

I have included this jar in my pom and also directly download and added as lib in my project, but this import doesn't work.

The `import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.RetryRunner` cannot be resolved.

[Reference link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/java-sdk/4.0.0/)

Comment: Seems to be part of the test code for watson: https://www.javatips.net/api/java-sdk-master/core/src/test/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/util/RetryRunner.java May not be part of the production release jar.

Comment: I am feeling Bluemix focus is on node.js not java, there most of the samples are in node.js. so what should I do ?

Comment: The same in version 6.6.0. This and such other useful functions should be available as maven dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RetryRunner class](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/a4a20febf056685f423e9fe4dbc56af4e54a4a14/core/src/test/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/util/RetryRunner.java) is not in the main package of the IBM Watson Java SDK.

It is a class from test package to support testing functionality for the IBM Watson java framework.

Clone the [IBM Watson java-sdk project](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) (it is open-source) to work with the RetryRunner class.